# Connecting Node.JS and Socket.IO external

Tags: node.js, socket.io, push

I've been playing around with NodeJS & socket.io to realize a push api & filewatcher.

I've looking at this example:
http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/nodejs-and-a-simple-push-notification-server/

I got the server up and running and when the XML changes the server will push the notification.
I only see the data change if i go to localhost:8000. If i just open the file node.html it will stay blank and gives a error (in the debug) that socket.io can't be found (404).

What am I doing wrong or do i need to add to the code?

This is the code (server.js):

```
    var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    parser = new require('xml2json'),
    fs = require('fs');

// creating the server ( localhost:8000 )
app.listen(8000);

// on server started we can load our client.html page
function handler(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/node.html', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading node.html');
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}

// File watcher
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log(__dirname);
    // watching the xml file
    fs.watch(__dirname + '/cache/file.xml', function(curr, prev) {
        // on file change we can read the new xml
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/cache/file.xml', function(err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // parsing the new xml data and converting them into json file
            var json = parser.toJson(data);
            // adding the time of the last update
            json.time = new Date();
            // send the new data to the client
            socket.volatile.emit('file', json);
        });
    });
});
```

node.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- 
     * Author:      Gianluca Guarini
     * Contact:     gianluca.guarini@gmail.com
     * Website:     http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/
     * Twitter:     @gianlucaguarini
    -->
        <title>Push notification server</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="file"></div>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // creating a new websocket
    var socket = io.connect('192.168.1.11:8000/');

    // on every message recived we print the new datas inside the #container div
    socket.on('file', function (data) {
        // convert the json string into a valid javascript object
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#file').html(data);
    });


    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.2.103:3000/');
// btw. var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');



socket.on('int', function(sender,passwort, x,y,z,xr,yr,zr){

            //es werden nur Parameter von sender name mit dem passwort pw   
            //akzeptiert!

            if( sender == "name" & passwort == "pw"){
            zwSchrauberX = x;
            zwSchrauberY = y;
            zwSchrauberZ = z;
            zwSchrauberXr = (xr%360)*2*pi/360;
            zwSchrauberYr = (yr%360)*2*pi/360;
            zwSchrauberZr = (zr%360)*2*pi/360;
            //console.log(zwSchrauberX);
            //console.log(zwSchrauberY);
            //console.log(zwSchrauberZ);                
            document.getElementsByTagName('p')[2].innerHTML ="Nachricht von:"+sender + "<br>" + " x:" +x+ " y:" +y+" z:"+z + "<br>" + ' xr:' +(xr%360)+'; yr:' +(yr%360)+'; zr:'+(zr%360)+ "<br>" +" Zeit:"+ new Date().getTime();

            }
        });
```

//The Server: index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var xl = 0;
var yl = 0;
var zl= 0;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});



io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

 socket.on('int2', function(x,y,z){
    io.emit('int', x,y,z);
  });

 socket.on('int', function(sender,passwort, x,y,z,xr,yr,zr){
    io.emit('int', sender,passwort, parseFloat(x),parseFloat(y),parseFloat(z),parseFloat(xr),parseFloat(yr),parseFloat(zr));
  });

 socket.on('val', function(){
        io.emit('int', xl,yl,zl);
  }); 

});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

The index.html


<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 10%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }

      form2 { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form2 input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 10%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form2 button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="x" autocomplete="off", onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/, '');"/>
      <input id="y" autocomplete="off", onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/, '');" />
      <input id="z" autocomplete="off", onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/, '');"/>
      <input id="xr" autocomplete="off", onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/, '');" />
      <input id="yr" autocomplete="off", onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/, '');" />
      <input id="zr" autocomplete="off", onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/, '');"/>
      <button>Send</button>
      <button id="n1">TestSend</button>
    </form>



     <form action="">

    </form>



    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>


      var socket = io();
      var username ='';
      var passwort ='';
      var count = 0;
      var array_x = new Array(0);
      var array_y = new Array(0);
      var array_z = new Array(0);



        $('#x').val('0');
        $('#y').val('0');
        $('#z').val('0');
        $('#xr').val('0');
        $('#yr').val('0');
        $('#zr').val('0');

        username = prompt('Your name:', username)|| '';

        passwort = prompt('Passwort:', passwort)|| '';

      $('n1').submit(function(){
        //socket.emit('chat message', username+ ': '+ $('#x').val());
        socket.emit('val');

        return false;
      });   

      $('form').submit(function(){
        //socket.emit('chat message', username+ ': '+ $('#x').val());
        socket.emit('int', username,passwort, $('#x').val(), $('#y').val(), $('#z').val(),$('#xr').val(), $('#yr').val(), $('#zr').val());

        return false;
      });


    socket.on('int', function(sender,passwort, x,y,z,xr,yr,zr){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text('Gesendet von:'+sender+ ' x:' +x+'+ y:' +y+' z:'+z + ' xr:' +xr+'; yr:' +yr+'; zr:'+zr));

    $('#x').val(x);
    $('#y').val(y);
    $('#z').val(z);
    $('#xr').val(xr);
    $('#yr').val(yr);
    $('#zr').val(zr);

    array_x[count] = parseFloat(x);
    array_y[count] = parseFloat(y);
    array_z[count] = parseFloat(z);
    count++;
    console.log(array_x);
    console.log(array_y);
    console.log(array_z);
  });

</script>
```

More source code:
http://socket.io/
https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example